# How to get LAC and CID of any Phone number

Tags: network-programming, gsm

I have an android app Net-monitoring which shows the LAC and CID of my working sim card but there is no option to type a mobile number of anyone else. I want to obtain ***LAC and CID*** of ***someone else's phone number***, who is living 800/km away. What should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just have their phone number then you can't get this.

Taking a example if they are staining beside you and have the same network provider they will likely have the same LAC and CID as you, but if they are on the other side of the country then their LAC and CID will reflect the cell they are connected to there.

In simple terms the LAC and CID depend on the users locations while the number remains constant no mater where they are so you can't get the CID and LAC just from the number itself.

If for your use case, however, you have some control of the others users device, or it is part of a set owned by a company or organisation, then you could have an app run on that phone which responds to a notification or SMS you send, for example, and queries and returns the LAC and CID.